# How to set values of a Plone autoform in update methode with ignoreContext = True

Tags: plone, zope

I'm trying to make a form where I'm storing values outside of the context. Storing is done and working well but now I would like the update method to fill the form on rendering process. So I'm overriding update method of the Form class that way:

```
def update(self):
    super(ConfigurationForm,self).update()
    form = self.request.form
    if not form:
        #We are on a rendering process
        provider = self.getProvider()
        settings = provider.get()
        #TODO: update widget values !?
```

settings is a dict where keys are equals to Interface fields's names.

So I have tried many ways to update widgets values:

- Using dataconverter (too much complex and don't know if this is the only way
- Updating the self.request.form dict and call again the update method
- playing with field objects

What is the good way to achieve this ? (supporting all kind of field ?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do ignoreContext. Override getContent() to return a dict instead. The dict will be used as a pseudo context.

Comment: Thank you @optilude for your answer. Wrong key words used while searching for this.